Интеграционное тестирование в MSTest
При интеграционном тестировании подготовка, действие, подготовка для утверждения - всё занимает довольно длительное время.
Использую MSTest
Я делаю:

Подготовка
Действие
Много утверждений

Если в Assert нет какого либо комментария. сложности с определением в каком именно сбой.
Было бы наверно правильно, каждый Assert в разном упорядоченном методе проводить с ранее выполненной одной подготовкой и действием на все, но в том же MSTest упорядочивание возможно только по алфавиту).
Как вы выкручиваетесь? Пишите комментарии?
Псевдокод
[TestMethod]
public async Task UnitWorkAsync() 
{
    // Подготовка
    await TestHelper.CleanDataBaseAsync();
    await TestHelper.FillDataBaseAsync();
    MyComponent myComponent = MakeMyComponent();

    // Действие
    for (int i = 0; i < TestHelper.DataList.Count; i++)
    {
        await myComponent.UnitWorkAsync();
    }

    // Подготовка для утверждений
    List<MyObject> myObjects = await TestHelper.GetMyObjectsFromDataBaseAsync();

    // Утверждение
    Assert.IsTrue(myObjects.Count > 0);
    // ...  и т.д. много Assert
}


Не совсем понял что вы хотите. А что вам мешает использовать другой тестовый фреймворк, более продвинутый? Обычно в них можно описать подготовительную часть, которая будет запускаться перед запуском остальных тестов и готовить тестовую среду - например, создавать тестовую БД.

@CrazyElf попробовал переформулировать, но наверно да, другой фреймворк надо, где как минимум упорядочевание возможно(

Я так понимаю, речь идет о классических составляющих теста Arrange, Act, Assert. Вам нужно диагностировать, какой код больше всего выполняется по времени. Для этого можно воспользоваться, например, стандартным StopWatch и добавить измерения в различных местах кода. Assert не должен занимать много времени. Проблема либо в Arrange, либо в Act

@AndreiKhotko проблема и в подготовке для Assert. Например, я произвёл Act, в базе данных прошли изменения, мне нужно теперь получить данные из базы, проежде чем сделать Assert .

@Xzizz тогда логично, конечно, организовать тесты таким образом, чтобы изначально создавалась временная БД с, возможно, заранее вставленными данными, затем по очереди каждый тестовый сценарий проверять на подготовленной БД. Было бы здорово, если бы вы привели конкретный код тестов, чтобы мы могли дать рекомендации

@AndreiKhotko попробовал на псеввдокоде продемонстрировать

В общем, я бы xUnit какой-нибудь попробовал припахать https://habr.com/ru/articles/265501/

@Xzizz цикл в 100 итераций в тесте выглядит странным. Зачем 100 итераций? Почему не 1, или не 2, например? И clean database как правило можно не делать, а просто каким-то образом научиться разграничивать данные между тестами. В реальных условиях у вас ведь приложение не будет работать каждый раз на чистой базе, верно?  P.S. увидел, что вы заполняете базу. Но очистка все равно занимает время. По возможности, её нужно избегать.

@AndreiKhotko про итерации это просто надо было что то в цикл псевдокода впихнуть) В TestHelper есть List с данными, которые заливаются и на самом деле в цикле вставляется число c количеством этих данных, которые компонент обрабатывает. А дальше в тех же Assert проверяет всё ли сходится и т.д. Обновил

Чтобы не тратить время на создание базы можно один раз её создать, а потом просто копировать готовый файл с базой, мне кажется это будет гораздо быстрее.

Чтобы не создавать и не заполнять БД для каждого теста, следует создать её один раз в начале серии тестов и использовать транзакции без коммита (с отменой - rollback) в каждом тесте. | Если используется Entity Framework, то Testing against your production database system. Без EF суть та же: оборачиваем SQL-запросы в транзакции.

@Xzizz И все равно не понимаю, зачем вам запускать UnitWorkAsync много раз? Почему бы не запустить 1-2 раза и проверить изменения в базе? Это сильно сократит время выполнения тестов

@AndreiKhotko Компонент просто так устроен. Он по сути сортировщик входных данных, по другим разным таблицам распихивает.  И за 1 еденицу работы его полную работоспособность не проверить. Я затем беру данные с разных таблиц и проверях что всё верно. Да, мой косяк, я не указал в псевдокоде что с разных мест потом тащу данные. Или я не понимаю вопрос.

@Xzizz т.е. UnitWorkAsync просматривает какую-то таблицу, где расположены некоторые сырые входящие данные (назовем ее "Input"), затем как-то с ними работает и в зависимости от "типа" входящих данных разбрасывает их по разным наборам таблиц (для типа X кидает в таблицы X1, X2, X3, для типа Y - в Y1, Y2, Y3). Все верно?

@AndreiKhotko да, но я бы сказал скорее просто тип A в таблицу A, тип B в таблицу B, тип C в таблицу C, без 1,2,3

@Xzizz тогда я бы писал тесты таким образом: 1) UnitWorkAsync_InputTypeA_MovesDataToTableA, 2) UnitWorkAsync_InputTypeB_MovesDataToTableB. и т.д. В тесте №1 - создать запись с типом A в таблице Input и выполнить UnitWorkAsync. В Assert проверить, что в таблице A появились правильные данные. Аналогично и для других тестов. Появится новый тип входящих данных - просто нужно будет дописать 1 доп. тест.

@Xzizz и еще вопрос: т.е. выходит, что у вас одно выполнение UnitWorkAsync забирает 1 запись из таблицы Input? Если это так, то может стоит пересмотреть подход и забирать сразу все записи, которые еще не обработаны, из таблицы? Или хотя бы N штук? N = 10 000, например.

@AndreiKhotko, да, одну. Скорее всего, всё что там есть и надо в итоге забирать. Было бы правильнее, оптимизированее, быстрее. Но пока это просто концепт, хорошая мысля приходит опосля xD

@Xzizz учиться на своих ошибках - самое ценное. :) Просто представьте, что у вас накопилось 10000 записей в таблице, и вы в своем приложении будете вытаскивать по одной записи 10000 раз, а это 10000 запросов к базе. Мало того что вы будете создавать лишнюю нагрузку на базу, так еще и приложение будет обрабатывать эти 10000 записей гораздо дольше, чем могло бы. Поэтому  следует все же пересмотреть реализацию
